# How to show Calendar in IPhone app source as iCal (.ics)file

Tags: iphone, icalendar

I am planning to create an iPhone application which displays tasks in calendar view with sort options Day, Week and Month view.

Those tasks comes from .ics file which will be in web site (server).

is it, We have to read that .ics file using our code and connect those tasks to calendar or we can directly set .ics file as a source.

Please give me ideas to create this application, thanks